# sendgrid - How to get the email id of a just sent email

Tags: python, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using python and sendgrid to send emails from my application.

I successfully integrated with Sendgrid and I am able to send emails BUT I am not understanding where can I find the message_id of an email I just sent.

I need such id so I can store it on my end and later on re-use it retrieve informations about the email from sendgrid.

I checked the response but there is no trace of the message id.

This is the code I am using

```
#define to emails
to_emails = [(outreach.contact.email, outreach.contact.name_surname)]
#define cc emails
cc_emails = [(outreach.contact.owner.email, outreach.contact.owner.first_name + ' ' + outreach.contact.owner.last_name),]
##Adding PM e PC in cc to all emails
CCs = outreach.position.jobproject.crew.filter(
                        Q(position_status=POSITION_STATUS[3][0]) &
                        (Q(title__title_name='Production Coordinator') |
                         Q(title__title_name='Production Manager') |
                         Q(title__title_name='Producer')
                         )
                    )

print(CCs)
for cc in CCs:
    cc_emails.append((cc.booked.email,cc.booked.name_surname))

#define bcc emails
#bcc_emails = [('test@gmail.com', outreach.contact.owner.first_name + ' ' + outreach.contact.owner.last_name)]

#define message object
message = Mail(
    from_email = (SENDER, outreach.contact.owner.first_name + ' ' + outreach.contact.owner.last_name),
    to_emails = to_emails,
    subject = outreach.emails.filter(action = email_action)[0].subject,
    html_content = outreach.emails.filter(action = email_action)[0].body
)


#add cc to message
for cc in cc_emails:
    if cc[0] != to_emails[0][0]:
        message.add_cc(cc[0])

#add bcc to message
#for bcc in bcc_emails:
#    message.add_bcc(bcc[0])

#add reply to to message
message.reply_to = (
    outreach.contact.owner.email,
    outreach.contact.owner.first_name + ' ' + outreach.contact.owner.last_name
)



sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient(SENDGRID_API_KEY)
response = sendgrid_client.send(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Activity APIs](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/email-activity/filter-all-messages) to get this info or start to use the Event Webhook.
Here are some useful links to get you started:

- https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/analytics-and-reporting/email-activity-feed
- https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook
- https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event
- https://sendgrid.com/blog/leveraging-sendgrids-event-api/
- https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/libraries#python

Hope this helped!